# Update HTML table value based on input in another field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

first time for me to ask a question here but have enjoyed the insight of many other posts over the years. I'm trying to update a field in my HTML table based on what the user selects from another field, but I need to get the value via a PHP query. Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <td style="width:25%;">
    <?php
        echo '<select onblur="CheckProduct()" id="GetProduct[]" name="GetProduct[]" required>';
        echo '<option value =""></option>';
        $sql = "SELECT ProdCode, ProdDescription, OrgCode, SKU FROM whproducts"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row["ProdCode"] . "'>" . $row["ProdCode"] . " - " . 
                $row["ProdDescription"] . "</option>"; 
        }
        }
        echo '</select>';   
    ?>         
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" id="Description"></td>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function CheckProduct() {
        var pcode = $(this).closest('tr').find('GetProduct').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkproduct.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'pcode': pcode;
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('Description').val(data);
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP (checkproduct.php file)

```
<?php
        $servername = "XXX"; 
        $username = "XXX";
        $password = "XXX";
        $dbname = "XXX"; 
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $code = $_POST['pcode']; 
        $sql = "SELECT ProdDescription FROM whproducts WHERE ProdCode='" . $code ."'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo $result; 
    ?>
```

Nothing happens when I run this and I'm not sure if it is actually possible to pass some data back from the PHP execution to the Javascrip/Ajax function.

Comment: `name="GetProduct[]"` suggests that you have multiple of these fields (generated in a loop?) - but then you would be creating duplicate IDs with `id="GetProduct[]"`, which is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: `.find('GetProduct')` - that would look for an element with the _tag name_ `GetProduct`

Comment: .find('GetProduct') isn't going to find anything. Use a class or id selector, not a tag selector

Comment: `var pcode = $(this)` - and `this` is probably `window` here, and not the select element. You much rather should bind this event handler _via_ jQuery as well, than use HTML attributes for that.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0):

Delegate!

Also a cell does not have a val() it has text()

If you change the cell with description to have a class instead of an ID then the code is simple.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myLinesTable').on('change', '[name^=GetProduct]', function() {
    const pcode = $(this).val();
    const $desc = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description');
    console.log(pcode)
    $.post('checkproduct.php', {
      pcode
    }, function(data) {
      $desc.val(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myLinesTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">
        <select class="productselect" name="GetProduct[]" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="ProdCode1">Prodcode1 - ProdDescription 1</option>
          <option value="ProdCode2">Prodcode2 - ProdDescription 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width:25%;" class="description"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternative

In this example I also changed the id of the select to a class 'productselect' and I take the description from the selected option

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myLinesTable').on('change', '.productselect', function() {
    const pcode = $(this).val();
    const desc = $('option:selected,this').text().split(' - ')[1];
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.description').text(desc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="myLinesTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">
        <select class="productselect" name="GetProduct[]" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="ProdCode1">Prodcode1 - ProdDescription 1</option>
          <option value="ProdCode2">Prodcode2 - ProdDescription 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width:25%;" class="description"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Mplungjan, thanks heaps for your reply and assistance. Yes, that's right. My table has an ID called "myLinesTable" and I updated this into your code. Unfortunately it doesn't update that row element with the "Description" ID though. Not sure why not, your code makes sense to me. If I can get this working it's going to solve a lot of problems for me. Any further assistance you can provide would be great!

Comment: @ChrisChalmers My bad, I did not complete the code - change the cell with description to have a class instead of an ID and then you can use the code I posted above. In the second example I also changed the id of the select to a class 'productselect' and I take the description from the selected option

Comment: @mplugjan, thanks, nice try, but still doesn't work. I appreciate your efforts. I copied the code exactly as you had, and tried a few variations etc. But still can't get it to run :(. I'll repost the code I'm now using.

Comment: JAVASCRIPT:$(function() {
   $('#myLinesTable').on('change', '[name^=GetProduct]', function() { // name starts with GetProduct
  const pcode = $(this).val();
  const $desc = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description');
  console.log(pcode)
  $.post('checkproduct.php',{ 
   pcode 
  }, function(data) {
   $desc.val(data); 
  });
   });
 });

Comment: HTML:   <select class="productselect" name="GetProduct[]" required>
     <option value =""></option>
        
     <?php
      
      $sql = "SELECT ProdCode, ProdDescription, OrgCode, SKU FROM whproducts"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row["ProdCode"] . "'>" . $row["ProdCode"] . " - " . $row["ProdDescription"] . "</option>"; 
       }
      }
     ?>   
      
     </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="description"></td>

Comment: And I added this just before my <table id="myLinesTable"> field:  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please update your QUESTION with the RENDERED table - I do not have any use for your PHP and had to mock something up myself

Comment: Did you close the `</script>` ?

Comment: And as mentioned it is `$desc.text(data);`, not `.val(data)`

Comment: Does the php return data? (Look in the console/network tab)